# How to get sender ExchangeUser and mailaddress for Outlook.MeetingItem

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, interop

When users accept/deny a calendar meeting request, and the organiser opens the confirmation/rejection message, the object type of the Inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MeetingItem.

MeetingItem does not seem to expose the Sender property. How can I get the Sender.GetExchangeUser() equivalent of a MeetingItem?

Like MailItem, the MeetingItem exposes a SenderEmailType property, which can hold the value "EX", meaning the SenderEmailAddress does not contain the actual email address. Microsoft has nicely [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-the-smtp-address-of-the-sender-of-a-mail-item) how to get the sender of a an Outlook.MailItem by usage of the Sender property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve `PR_SENDER_ENTRYID` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C190102`) or `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00410102`) using `MeetingItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`, convert it to a hex string using `PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString` and use it to call `Namespace.GetAddressEntryFromID`.